# Remote Service(Bluetooth connection) and a other Activity

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-activity, android-service

I'm trying to start a remote Service by an Activity. The Service should handle a Bluetooth Connection to a device(CAN Bluetooth gateway). I thought of using a Messenger to handle the Connection between the Activities and the Service.
After the Connection is established I want to switch to next Activity were I want to create data which I want to send to my device. I tried the the example from [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) but it isn't working. Is there something special??

Thx

Comment: This should work without problems but without any code no use. Btw I guess this is dead topic now? Admins, maybe?